# SSIS OleDb error redirect fails with flatfile destination

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I have an ssis package that reads an `OLEDB Source` and writes to a `Flat File Destination` , where I've tried to redirect errors, but it doesn't seem to be working.

The transforms look like this:
[image: transform layout]

The error redirect looks like:
[image]

But when I run the package, I get this in the execution results:

[image]

So, i have a truncation error, the redirect should capture that, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was trying to catch a truncation error, and the only way I could find that worked was a conditional output, any csv field values larger that my db table were redirected to a output file that was emailed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the length of the column in the error output of the `OLEDB Source`

1. Right click on the `OOD facts_item1`
2. Go to `Show Advanced Editor`
3. Go to `Input and Output properties` Tab
4. Click on `OLEDB Source Error Output`
5. Increase `OemPart` column length

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work either.  The error I was running into was a truncation, so I fixed with the method below.